# Unit Testing in ts-jest with TypeOrm entities

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, typeorm

Am trying to write tests, but am getting error. i think i have problem with connection.
"Cannot execute operation on "default" connection because connection is not yet established."

i have tests folder, and in it am having `user.spec.ts` and `testhelper.ts`

testhelper.ts

```
// import { Connection, createConnection } from "typeorm";
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from "typeorm";

import Database from "better-sqlite3";

export class TestHelper {
  private static _instance: TestHelper;

  private constructor() {}

  public static get instance(): TestHelper {
    if (!this._instance) this._instance = new TestHelper();

    return this._instance;
  }

  private dbConnect!: DataSource;
  private testdb!: any;
  async setupTestDB() {
    this.testdb = new Database(":memory:", { verbose: console.log });

    this.dbConnect = new DataSource({
      name: "default",
      type: "better-sqlite3",
      database: ":memory:",
      entities: ["src/entity/**/*.ts"],
      synchronize: true,
    } as DataSourceOptions);
  }

  teardownTestDB() {
    this.dbConnect.destroy();
    this.testdb.close();
  }
}
```

user.spec.ts

```
import { createUser } from "../src/controllers/user.controller";
//@ts-ignore
import { TestHelper } from "./testhelper";

beforeAll(async () => {
  await TestHelper.instance.setupTestDB();
});

afterAll(() => {
  TestHelper.instance.teardownTestDB();
});

describe("User Tests", () => {
  test("should create user", async () => {
    const body = {
      firstname: "John",
      lastname: "Brut",
      email: "john@examle.com",
      password: "password123",
    };
    const res = {};
    //@ts-ignore
    const user = await createUser(body, res);
    //@ts-ignore
    expect(user.firstname).toBe("John");
    //@ts-ignore
    expect(user.lastname).toBe("Brut");
  });
});
```

I'm doing this first time. and am stuck on it very long time... can someone please help me with this... : (

Comment: I don't see where you initialize the connection.
await dbConnect.initialize()

Comment: Thanks for response. i added await this.dbConnect.initialize(); and now i have connection. need help with one more thing. am getting error on test  i think am giving data wrong way in createUser method it's waiting for req.body but in here i'm giving data in const body so i don't think it's the right way to do it

Comment: this is my usercreate method. what's i'm doing wrong in  user.spec.ts const { firstname, lastname, email, password } = req.body;
const user = new User();
    user.firstname = firstname;
    user.lastname = lastname;
    user.email = email;
    user.password = password;
    user.avatar = fileName;
    await user.save();    return res.json({
      success: true,
      user,
    });

Comment: do yo need to test only database operations or http requests to api? 
If http requests you need to mock them too.

Comment: In this moment i just want to test database operations, crud operations...

Comment: You seem to have imported controller, that got me confused. If you only need to insert to database, you can do it using something like dbConnect.manager.create(User, userObject)

Comment: in user.spec.ts  i have this now beforeAll(async () => {
  await TestHelper.instance.setupTestDB();
});

afterAll(() => {
  TestHelper.instance.teardownTestDB();
});

describe("User Tests", () => {
  test("should create user", async () => {
    await User.insert({
      firstname: "John",
      lastname: "Brut",
      email: "john@examle.com",
      password: "password123",
    });

    const user = await User.find({
      where: {
        id: 1,
      },
    });
    expect(user[0].firstname).toBe("John");
  });
});  am getting DataSource is not set for this entity.

Comment: it's need coneection i think what u answered i need that something like this dbConnect.manager.create(User, userObject)  how can i import  dbConnect to my user.spec.ts ?

Comment: You don't need the user.spec.ts file for the thing I said. You can't use UserRepository this way in this codebase. Are you sure you don't want to test http request? What is this userController? is this coming from a framework?

Comment: It's just user create method export const createUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const { firstname, lastname, email, password } = req.body;
    const user = new User();
    user.firstname = firstname;
    user.lastname = lastname;
    user.email = email;
    user.password = password;

    await user.save();

    return res.json({
      success: true,
      user,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof Error) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: e.message,
      });
    }
  }
};

Comment: Yes, i need http request, because this user create method is http request. i just was thinking that it was in category database testing... lol my bad

Comment: your function seems simple enough to test without http request I edited the code in the answer for that purpose. But for the http requests. It is complicated to tell howto here
you should learn to use supertest or equivalent library. https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest

Answer (score 1):

try this way, testhelper.ts

```
  async setupTestDB() {
    this.testdb = new Database(":memory:", { verbose: console.log });

    this.dbConnect = new DataSource({
      name: "default",
      type: "better-sqlite3",
      database: ":memory:",
      entities: ["src/entity/**/*.ts"],
      synchronize: true,
    } as DataSourceOptions);
    await this.dbConnect.initialize()
  }
```

Comment: Yes, i did it and it's connected but i have problem with tests i commented you about it. can u please help me with this to if u know how to do it? thanks again for helping with connection :)

Comment: i copied your code. am getting TypeError: res.status is not a function

      29 |   } catch (e) {
      30 |     if (e instanceof Error) {
    > 31 |       return res.status(400).json({
         |                  ^
      32 |         message: e.message,
      33 |       });
      34 |     }

Comment: hmm you use a framework right?

Comment: i use express and typeorm

Comment: req and res must come through middleware then. supertest  is the easiest way in my opinion. https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest

Comment: I did like this: describe("test create route", () => {
  const user = {
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "Pupkin",
    email: "john@example.com",
    password: "123@Saiuo09!",
  };
  test("Should have success and user", async () => {
    const mockCreateUser = jest.fn((): any => user);

    jest.spyOn(User, "create").mockImplementation(() => mockCreateUser());

    const res = await request(app).post("/api/v1/users").send(user);

    expect(res.body).toHaveProperty("success");
    expect(res.body).toHaveProperty("user");
  });
});

Comment: but i'm getting this error:    Received value: {"message": "DataSource is not set for this entity."}

Comment: When you run express does it work? is "User" entity or repository? Typeorm can work more than one way in express, there are many possibilities can go wrong. Also entities string might have failed to resolve due to a bug in typeorm.

Comment: yes, it's works User is entity @Entity("users")
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstname: string;  other fileds...... }

Comment: try importing and referencing the entity in the  entities: ["src/entity/**/*.ts"] instead of glob string. And that is the limit I could help short of cloning your project :)